# execute bashscript in background?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a bash script that runs a backup command. The script runs great. However because its backups up everything, it takes a while for the script to execute successfully.

Can you execute a script from terminal and have it execute in a background of the terminal?

Right now I have to open up a new terminal window because the script takes a couple hours because I cannot enter a command in the same terminal that I executed the bash script until the bash script is finished.

I would think that this is possible seeing if I ran the bashscript on system startup, the script would run in the background.

Comment: simplest way: `./bashscript &`. otherwise, google `screen` and `nohup`.

Comment: sweet nohup should work!

Answer (score 3):

If you close the terminal it will closes the process of script execution. If you want to run the script in the background and don't want the current window to be the parent of the process execute this:

```
./bash_script &
```

And the important part is to run next

```
exit
```

This will reparent the process to the OS and the process will run really in the background. So you can quit terminal.

Answer (score 1):

easily,
only use

```
nohup ./your_script.sh &
```